# Python Plotly Heatmap Datetime only showing portion

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, plotly, heatmap

I am defining a heatmap datetime series with a binary z value.

The output of go.Heatmap seems to be correct...however, the plot only shows a very tiny portion of it..

Can anyone help debug? I am not setting any limits (nor am I setting anything at all) for the layout component.

```
{'colorscale': 'Viridis',
 'type': 'heatmap',
 'x': [datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 5),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 10),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 15),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 20),
       .....
       all the way to index 719],
 'y': ['MotionSensor'],
 'z': ['1',
       '1',
       '1',
       '0',
       '0',
       '0',
       '0',
       '0',
       .....
       all the way to index 719]}
```

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways a heatmap would go wrong.

let me point out the ones that apply for your case!

1. `Z-Axis` elements are given as string, but we need to pass it as number, that is why you are getting the color scale all wrong. You can do something like this to get all number.

   ```
   arr = ['1', '1', '1', '0']
   [int(i) for i in arr]
   ```

This will give us a list of numbers instead of strings

2. The `Z-axis` elements should be a list of lists (`Ex: [[1], [2], [3]])`) Where the first list corresponds to the values of each `Y-Axis` and its corresponding `X-Axis` values. Something like:

   ```
   Y: 1, X: [1, 2, 3], Z: [1234,1234566,56456]
   Y: 2, X: [1, 2, 3], Z: [5345,2346,7654]
   ```

   So this can be set to the heatmap properties as:

   ```
   {x: [1, 2, 3],
   y: [1,2],
   z: [ [1234,1234566,56456], [5345,2346,7654] ] }
   ```

Try out these changes and let me know if the layout issue still occours.

Here is some working sample code for reference

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly  as py
from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

trace = go.Heatmap(z=
[[int(i) for i in ['1',
       '1',
       '1',
       '0']]],
                   x= [datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 5),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 10),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 15),
       datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 4, 12, 0, 20)],
                   y=['MotionSensor'])
data=[trace]
py_offline.iplot(data, filename='labelled-heatmap')
```